# Map df array column with dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, mapping

I have a dataframe which has columns of arrays:

```
id_food1    id_food2
[1]       NaN
[2]       NaN
[2 3]     [1]
```

I want to map thse columns to a dict with values:

```
food_dict = {1: 'cake', 
               2: 'choco', 
               3: 'cream'}
```

I want to have something like this :

```
id_food1    id_food2  id_food1_name  id_food2_name
[1]       NaN.        [cake]          0
[2]       NaN         [choco]        0
[2 3]     [1]          [choco,cream] [cake]
```

I know how to do it when the columns are not array like this

```
data['id_food1_name'] = data['id_food1'].map(food_dict)
```

but unable to do it when it is an array.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Your dataframes seems to have two column with the same name

Comment: yes sorry I edited it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) for flatten values, mapping and last aggregate list pre index:

```
data['id_food1_name'] = (data['id_food1'].explode().astype(float)
                                  .map(food_dict).groupby(level=0).agg(list))
```

For all columns:

```
#converting strings to lists
import ast

c = ['id_food1', 'id_food2']

def f(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except:
        return np.nan
data[c] = data[c].applymap(f)
```

Alternative solution for convert to lists:

```
data[c] = data[c].stack().str.strip('[]').str.split().unstack()
```

And then mapping

```
for x in c:
    f = lambda x: [food_dict.get(int(y)) for y in x if int(y) in food_dict]
    data[f'{x}_name'] = data[x].dropna().apply(f)
    data[f'{x}_name'] = data[f'{x}_name'].fillna(0)
print (data)
  id_food1 id_food2   id_food1_name id_food2_name
0      [1]      NaN          [cake]             0
1      [2]      NaN         [choco]             0
2   [2, 3]      [1]  [choco, cream]        [cake]
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I am getting [nan] values i the name columns as of now

Comment: @Jazz - can you test now? I convert values to floats.

Comment: 'TypeError: explode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'
'

Comment: A very weird error with your oldier vapproach: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Comment: I have removed the int from here get(int(y)) it removes the error but gives me [none] as output to all the rows

Comment: @Jazz - added `f` function in EDITed answer. Because is necessary create lists from strings first.

Comment: I think it has worked. I will check over all and let you know in some time! Thanks agaih! :)

Comment: I think it works only when the array has 1 value and shows nan when array has 2 values

Comment: @Jazz - Can you try alternative solution `data[c] = data[c].stack().str.strip('[]').str.split().unstack()` instead `data[c] = data[c].applymap(f)` ?